# How to pass parameters to request during testing?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I run the test via Client(). post, but request.POST does not contain the passed dictionary

**test.py**

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.test.client import Client

class AccountTests(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.email = 's@s/com'
        self.name = 'John'
        self.mobile = "+799999999"

    def test_user_login(self):
        c = Client()
        response = c.post('/login-otp/',
                          {'email': self.email, 'name': self.name, 'mobile': self.mobile},
                          follow=True)
```

**views.py**

```
def login_otp(request):
    mobile = request.session['mobile'] # the interpreter does not see the "mobile" key
    context = {'mobile': mobile}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        otp = request.POST.get('otp')
```

Comment: Aren't you passing 'mobile' as a post parameter, instead of a session object, in your test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing `mobile` as a POST parameter.

Try this instead:

```py
def login_otp(request):
    mobile = request.POST['mobile']
    ...
```

Edit:

You can set session variables like this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.session

Comment: Your decision is clear. But I don't want to rewrite the application logic. How do I pass the "mobile" parameter to the session (request.session)?

Comment: my mistake is that in the application I take the parameters from the session, and in the test I write the parameters in the POST. But I don't know how to fix it in TestCase :-(

Comment: Edited it in the answer but here as well: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.session